# Arrange image views in flippable stack view as in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, stackview

1. Images like fragments in [FlippableStackView](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView) library.
2. I want stack in right side.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **View Flipper**

Refer below link

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.bartoszlipinski.flippablestackview.FlippableStackView
    android:id="@+id/flippable_stack_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:rotation="90"//will do the job
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```